# draw line doesn't work, what might be the problem?

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to draw the line by clicking the mouse on the first coordinate where the line should start and second coordinate where the line should end.
When I run my project nothing happens.
I cannot find out what my code is missing.

```
LONG WINAPI WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HDC hdc;
    BOOL fDraw = FALSE;
    POINT ptPrevious = { 0 };
    HPEN Pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 255));


    switch (Message) {
        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: {
            fDraw = TRUE;
            ptPrevious.x = LOWORD(lParam);
            ptPrevious.y = HIWORD(lParam);
            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP: {
            if (fDraw)
            {
                hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
                MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
                LineTo(hdc, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
                ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            }
            fDraw = FALSE;
            break;
        }


        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            if (fDraw)
            {
                hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
                MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
                LineTo(hdc, ptPrevious.x = LOWORD(lParam),
                    ptPrevious.y = HIWORD(lParam));
                ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
            }
            break;
        }


        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Draw to an off screen bitmap, and then paint it to screen WM_PAINT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because declared variables are local variables, variables can be declared with Static.

```
   static BOOL fDraw = FALSE;
   static POINT ptPrevious = { 0 };
```

In addition, you forget to use the SelectObject function to select pen into DC.

You can also use WM_PAINT redrawing to improve your code:

Example:

```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
   {
   HDC hdc;
   PAINTSTRUCT ps;
   static BOOL fDraw = FALSE;
   static BOOL fDraw_begin = FALSE;
   static POINT ptPrevious;
   static RECT rcClient; 
   static POINT pt;
   static HPEN Pen;

   switch (message)
   {
   case WM_CREATE:
   {
          Pen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(255, 0, 0));
          break;
   }

   case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
   {
          ptPrevious.x = (LONG)LOWORD(lParam);
          ptPrevious.y = (LONG)HIWORD(lParam);
          return 0;
   }

   case WM_LBUTTONUP:
   {
          if (fDraw = TRUE)
          {
                 fDraw = FALSE;
                 fDraw_begin = TRUE;
                 InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rcClient, TRUE);
                 UpdateWindow(hwnd);

          }
          return 0;
   }

   case WM_MOUSEMOVE: 
   {
          if (wParam && MK_LBUTTON)
          {
                 GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
                 hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
                 SetROP2(hdc, R2_NOTXORPEN);
                 if (!IsRectEmpty(&rcClient))      // Detecting whether the rectangular area is empty
                 {
                       MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
                       LineTo(hdc, (LONG)LOWORD(lParam),
                              (LONG)HIWORD(lParam));
                 }
                 MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
                 LineTo(hdc, (LONG)LOWORD(lParam),
                       (LONG)HIWORD(lParam));
                 pt.x = (LONG)LOWORD(lParam);
                 pt.y = (LONG)HIWORD(lParam);
                 fDraw = TRUE;

                 ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
          }      
          return 0;
   }

   case WM_PAINT:
   {
          hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
          SelectObject(hdc, Pen);
          if (fDraw_begin)
          {
                 fDraw_begin = FALSE;
                 MoveToEx(hdc, ptPrevious.x, ptPrevious.y, NULL);
                 LineTo(hdc, pt.x,
                       pt.y);
          }
          EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
          ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
          return 0;
   }

   case WM_DESTROY:
   {
          DeleteObject(Pen);
          PostQuitMessage(0);
          return 0;
   }

   }
   return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, the problem is because none of your data is persistent.  Since they are all local variables, their content disappears when `WndProc` returns.  `fDraw` is set to `FALSE` on every message, and will never be true for the WM_LBUTTONDOWN or WM_MOUSEMOVE messages.  Therefore nothing happens.

You'll want to create some sort of a class to hold `fDraw`, `ptPrevious`, and a structure to hold the coordinates of the line(s) to draw.  Use `InvalidateRect` in the WM_MOUSEMOVE and WM_LBUTTONUP messages.  Then only draw them in response to a WM_PAINT message (using the DC provided in the paint message).

Using the [`CWnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2017) MFC class can greatly simplify those tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not get the DC three times, get it once and release it on mouse up.
Also, your drawing will be eventually validated, so you need to log the mouse move and repeat this stuff in WM_PAINT handler.

Comment: so can i declare DC outside switch statement? can i just use WM_PAINT instead of WM_MOUSEMOVE?

Comment: In generic Windows apps, drawing is done in response to WM_PAINT. Drawing does not persist. This means that if your window is minimized, the next maximize won't show what you have drawn previously. That's why you draw it when Windows requests it, that is, in WM_PAINT.

When doing real time drawing, you can use GetDC() to get the DC, but also you save what you have drawn (in your case, the start/end xy), and repeat it with a memory DC in response to WM_PAINT.  So you can use GetDC() on WM_LBUTTONDOWN, but save the dc until WM_LBUTTONUP. Then log what you have drawn to redraw it in WM_PAINT.